# iOS swift imageView cannot be hidden in TableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiimageview, hidden

I recently added some swift code inside an objective-C project and I am facing something strange I cannot sort out.

I am using the Searchbar (from Ray tutorial) that I customized. In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, I can customize my cell labels and everything works fine. The only thing is that I cannot hide some imageViews according to if (BOOL) conditions. Something must be wrong with my swift code since I can hide those image in Objective-C files with the same if (BOOL) conditions.

Just in case I post my code if anyone can help me.

**In SearchVC (swift)**

```
class aCell : UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var some label...
    @IBOutlet weak var imageFacturation: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageMail: UIImageView!
}

class PatientSearchViewController : ...

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellSwift") as aCell // aCell is a class defined inside the file where I attach the label and imageView properties
    var person : ClassObject

    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
        person = filteredObjects[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        person = objects[indexPath.row]
    }

    // Configure the cell
    cell.labelLastname.text = person.lastname
    cell.labelFirstname.text = person.firstname

    if person.hasMailSent == false {
        cell.imageMail.hidden == true // --> does not work in swift code but is Hidden in objective-C with the setHidden:true
    }
    if person.hasFacturation == false {
        cell.imageFacturation.hidden == true // --> does not work in swift code but is Hidden in objective-C with the setHidden:true
    }

    return cell
}
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if person.hasMailSent == false {
    cell.imageMail.hidden == true // --> does not work in swift code but is Hidden in objective-C with the setHidden:true
}
if person.hasFacturation == false {
    cell.imageFacturation.hidden == true // --> does not work in swift code but is Hidden in objective-C with the setHidden:true
}
```

In the line `cell.imageMail.hidden == true` you are basically comparing and not assigning. It should simply be `cell.imageMail.hidden = true` if you want to assign the value.

Comment: Ahah such an awful beginner's mistake... so stupid of me. Thanks a lot :-)