# IOS Swift how can hide the space of an Image inside a TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, swift3

I have a tableView that contains a UIImageView and if the Image has a URL then the image displays and if not then no Image is displayed. The issue I have is that if there is no Image then a big blank spot occurs in the TableView as if there was an image. Is there a way to reduce the blank spot or hide it (Images below) ? The image is the big UIImageView in the center . This is my code when it comes to the Images

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyFeed", for: indexPath) as! MyFeed


    if stream_image_string[indexPath.row].characters.count > 2  {
        let strCellImageURL = self.stream_image_string[indexPath.row]
        let imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: strCellImageURL)!
        let request:NSURLRequest =  NSURLRequest(url: imgURL as URL)
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest,    completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

                cell.post_image.image = UIImage(data: data!)

            })
        });
        task.resume()
    } else {
    cell.post_image!.isHidden = true
        cell.post_image!.image = nil
    }


    return cell
}
```

Essentially if the String coming back has 2 or more characters then it's a valid URL and the image is downloaded; the part that I am focused on is the else statement and this code

```
else {
        cell.post_image!.isHidden = true
            cell.post_image!.image = nil
        }
```

So obviously if it goes in the else statement then there is no image and I set the Image to null or nil then I try to hide the extra white space by setting the Image to hidden however that does not work . Any idea on how I can hide the white space ? I have also been reading this question but it does not work [iOS swift imageView cannot be hidden in TableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27281831/ios-swift-imageview-cannot-be-hidden-in-tableviewcell)

[image: Big Image in the center]

[image]

Comment: The easiest way (I think) is to change width of image to 0

Comment: Create an outlet for imageView's width constraint and make its constant as zero when there is no image.

Comment: You can create two different cells if you want to use your image with outlet (custom image view) otherwise you should use image view as a runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give outlet of image's width and if there is no image then set constant of that outlet to "0".

e.g. 
if(!image)
{

widthOfImage.constant = 0

}

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem myself. You need to create 2 cells for this. Like this:

```
override func tableView (_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if (stream_image_string[indexPath.row] == "")
     {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell (withIdentifier: "noImageMyFeed", for: indexPath) as! noImageMyFeed
       return cell

     }
    else
     {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell (withIdentifier: "MyFeed", for: indexPath) as! MyFeed
       return cell
     }
    }
```

this video will help you in detail : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FAxtWtqeMIM

adapt the video to its own content, create a cell from scratch by simply deleting the image part